# R - regex match pattern and store only the pattern in a new column?

Tags: r, regex

I've been searching for hours. This should be very easy but I don't see how :(

I have a dataframe called ds that contains a column structured like:

```
name
"Doe, Mr. John"
"Worth, Miss. Jane"
```

I want to extract the middle word and put it into a new column.

```
#This is how I'm doing it now
ds$title <- NA

mr  <- grep(", Mr. ", ds$name)
miss <- grep(", Miss. ", ds$name)

ds$title[mr] <- ", Mr. "
ds$title[miss] <- ", Miss. "
```

I'm trying to generalize this with regex so that it'll take any middle word matching the pattern of *"comma space word period space"*

This is my best guess but it only removes the pattern:

```
gsub(", .+\\.+ ", "", ds$name)
```

**How do I keep the pattern and remove the rest?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a capture group.  Basically, you match the whole pattern, use a capture group to match the part you want to keep, and replace the whole match with the capture group:

```
# I often specify perl = TRUE, though it isn't necessary here
(ds$title <- gsub(".+(, .+\\.+ ).+", "\\1", ds$name, perl = TRUE))
#[1] ", Mr. "   ", Miss. "
```

The capture group is what's in the parentheses (`(, .+\\.+ )`), and you refer back to it with `\\1`.  If you had a second capture group, you'd refer to it as `\\2`.

Note that if you want to catch comma, space, word, period, space, then you could modify the capture group to `(, .+\\. )`.  You only need to match one period, not one or more.

---

A straightforward `stringi` alternative that does not use capture groups is `stri_extract_first_regex` (or in this case `stri_extract_last_regex` or `stri_extract_all_regex` work fine)

```
library(stringi)
ds$title <- stri_extract_first_regex(ds$name, ", .+\\. ")
#[1] ", Mr. "   ", Miss. "
```

and as thelatemail pointed out in a comment you can do a similar thing with base R, too, but it's a little harder to remember how to use the `regmatches` and `regexpr` functions:

```
regmatches(ds$name, regexpr(", .+\\. ", ds$name))
#[1] ", Mr. "   ", Miss. "
```

Comment: Is the `perl=` necessary? Seems to work ok without it for me.

Comment: @thelatemail `perl = TRUE` is not necessary here.  It's just my preference to specify it most of the time.

Comment: @Jota That's just what I was looking for. I was close but didn't know the capture notation. Thanks! Bonus: I read what the perl argument does but how often is it really necessary in practice or is it just a good rule of thumb?

Comment: It's necessary when you want to use perl-like regular expressions or use lookarounds.  Otherwise, it's not really necessary.  You can see more about what it allows under the "Perl-like Regular Expressions" section of `?regex`

Answer (score 1):

Matched capture groups are your BFF:

```
library(stringi)
library(purrr)

ds <- data.frame(name=c("Doe, Mr. John", "Worth, Miss. Jane"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

nonsp <- "[[:alnum:][:punct:]]+"
sp <- "[[:blank:]]+"

stri_match_all_regex(ds$name, nonsp %s+% sp %s+% "(" %s+% nonsp %s+% ")" %s+% sp %s+% nonsp) %>%
  map_chr(2)
## [1] "Mr."   "Miss."
```

For your "add column to a data frame" needs:

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

ds <- data.frame(name=c("Doe, Mr. John", "Worth, Miss. Jane"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

nonsp <- "[[:alnum:][:punct:]]+"
sp <- "[[:blank:]]+"

mutate(ds, title=stri_match_all_regex(ds$name, nonsp %s+% sp %s+% "(" %s+% nonsp %s+% ")" %s+% sp %s+% nonsp) %>% map_chr(2))
##                name title
## 1     Doe, Mr. John   Mr.
## 2 Worth, Miss. Jane Miss.
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but isn't this just a straight forward regex string extraction - `regmatches(ds$name, regexpr(", .+\\.+ ", ds$name))` or whatever the equivalent is in `str_extract` ?

Comment: Down-vote it if you believe the answer is wrong. This makes it a bit more generic and it's readable.

Comment: Thanks for the extra clean up piece!